# Jlabel size and alignment wont change

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am trying to make a rock paper scissors game for school and the title JLabel doesnt change its size or alignment. No matter what i put in `title.setAlignmentX();` it doesnt change but the vertical alignment works fine.

```
   public class Game extends JFrame implements MouseListener, ActionListener,KeyListener {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
         Game g = new Game();


    //frame
    JLabel title = new JLabel("ROCK PAPER SCISSORS");
    title.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,150));
    title.setAlignmentX(400);
    title.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
    title.setForeground(Color.black);
    g.setTitle("rockpaperscissors");
    g.setVisible(true);
    g.setResizable(false);
    g.setBounds(0,0,800,800);
    g.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.green);
    g.add(title);
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/

Comment: (1-) *JLabel doesnt change its size or alignment.* - that is not a requirement. What do you expect to happen? The size of the label is the size of the text. How should the size change? Do you want the text to be bigger? Again what kind of alignment are you expecting. Should it be left/right/center aligned? Any question should state what you see and what you expect to see. Also, why are you using "setAlignmentX". You stated vertical alignment works when you use "setVertcalAlignment", so why wouldn't you use "setHorizontalAlignment"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your code: `g.setLayout(new FlowLayout());`.

[image]

You can read more on Layouts and how to use them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).